# Where to specify Global database connection string while runnning Execute Sql Command from database project?

Tags: c#, sql, database

While running (F5) Stored Procedure from generated Schema of SQL server database project, I need to supply connection string (SQL Server connection window prompts). Morever the SP is firing against the default Master-database.

To resolve this I used "Use " in the beginning of the SP. But this is not viable because I need to provide "Use " for all 100's of SP's, and more over every time the conection string as well.

Is there any way where we can specify the connection string in CMD variable or config where it could be picked while running the SP from schema objects? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying a "Database" or "Initial Catalog" within your connection string?

Comment: Where do i need to specify the connection string, whenever i am trying to run the SP, SQL server Connection pops up, after providing the server name and password it exceutes it under master. How can we can get rid of supplying connection every time while running SP from generated Schema ( SQL Server database project ).

Comment: So you are always running the SP from within SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the "Initial Catalog" setting.

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/